# bash - execute jar on system init and shutdown gracefullly

Tags: linux, bash, unix, amazon-ec2, init

I have written an `/etc/rc.local` script which executes a jar file and automatically shuts down the system after completion. The script seems to start successfully but ends up shutting down before completion.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
mv --backup=t /tmp/rc.local.log /home/hadoop/logs  
exec 2> /tmp/rc.local.log  # send stderr from rc.local to a log file
exec 1>&2                      # send stdout to the same log file
set -x                         # tell sh to display commands before execution
touch /var/lock/subsys/local

EC2_INSTANCE_ID="`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id || die \"wget instance-id has failed: $?\"`"
test -n "$EC2_INSTANCE_ID" || die 'cannot obtain instance-id'
EC2_AVAIL_ZONE="`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone || die \"wget availability-zone has failed: $?\"`"
test -n "$EC2_AVAIL_ZONE" || die 'cannot obtain availability-zone'
EC2_REGION="`echo \"$EC2_AVAIL_ZONE\" | sed -e 's:\([0-9][0-9]*\)[a-z]*\$:\\1:'`"

##########
#run hadoop job
#############
su - hadoop -c 'java -jar /home/hadoop/my.jar'

##stop instance
/opt/aws/bin/ec2-stop-instances $EC2_INSTANCE_ID --region $EC2_REGION
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Does your jar run in daemon mode? Eg the parent process forks, launches a child and returns. If you run `java -jar /home/hadoop/my.jar`, does it return immediately to the prompt?

Comment: No the jar doesn't run in daemon mode. It blocks till completion if I run it from the console manually.

Answer (score 0):

set -x automatically shuts down the script if you get exit 1 or higher error.

if I am correction, your variables such as EC2_INSTANCE_ID
need to take away the double quotes. This is because all characters inside the double quotes are taken literal values except for $

try

```
EC2_INSTANCE_ID= `wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id || die wget instance-id has failed: "$?"`
```

Also I noticed you have decent error catching commands, so it is okay to take away set -x so you can see what errors you're getting before script exits.

I also never seen die command before.